# Caching proxy access control

Tags: proxy, cache

I want to use a caching proxy to force all connections on my page over SSL, and let the unsecure connection be handled by the proxy.

This proxy is accessible from the web.

Now I was wondering what's preventing anyone from using that proxy?

Basically what I need to do is display email content in a browser and the embedded assets should be proxied over SSL, like `https://myproxy.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Funsecure.com%2Fa.png`.

Comment: I posted an answer below but I fear this is an XY question. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because when I display email content in the webpage I loose the SSL browser badge because I'm loading unsecure content on a secure page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are displaying 3rd party e-mail content on your site (i.e your system downloads e-mail and displays it on a webpage). You should be pretty careful about the XSS risks in doing this and properly escape and render the content you receive. This is way easier said than done, especially if you want e-mails to keep their general look and feel.

GMail, for example, hides all third party content by default and if you choose to load it, the browser will actually show a warning sign over the "secure connection" indication. Should you choose to do this, using a separate domain would be a good idea. "It's good enough for Google" would probably be a decent enough justification for a customer.

Nothing is preventing anyone from using your proxy for any kind of content if you implement it in a naive way. You could add some sort of HTTP authentication to the server doing the proxying (cookie based, HTTP auth or TLS client side certificates). In a regular setting, cookie-based is probably the only option that makes sense. More sophisticated alternatives would involve parsing e-mail, extracting hotlinked resources and rewriting the URLs so that your proxy only receives specially-crafted proxying requests and not anything that your users put into the URL bar.

If you explain the general use and functionality of the system your are building I might be able to propose a better solution.

Comment: No I don't send the links over email, but I want to prefix all links in incoming email with the SSL caching proxy URL

Comment: Actually I'm using a sandboxed iframe to prevent XSS. Also I sanitize content and display a warning before loading external content.

Comment: Using cookie-based authentication with your proxy should be enough to prevent unauthorized use of the system then. You might want to use a cache and limit the size of the proxy'd requests to prevent DoS scenarios if you expect a significant amount of users.

Comment: Relevant: GMail now proxies images http://gmailblog.blogspot.ie/2013/12/images-now-showing.html